# Bootstrap Image Gallery by blueimp: How to disable the wheel handler and keyboard handler

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

How can I disable the mouse wheel handler and the keyboard arrow keys that currently navigate the modal gallery to the next image?

Here is the demo site: http://blueimp.github.com/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/.

If you click on one of the image a modal pop up and if you use your mouse to scroll down or press your arrow keys, it'll go to the next image. I would like for user to only be able to click on the actual navigation button and prevent any accident of scrolling down the modal to see more but instead goes to the next image when it's unintended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way i can think of is if you are hosting the code yourself - the handlers are bootstrap-image-gallery.js:

- keyHandler at line 235
- wheelHandler at line 249

Those only do prev() and next() so if you don't want that functionality you can just comment it out I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Unbind the mousewheel and keydown event handlers created by Bootstrap Image Gallery

```
$(function() { 
  $('#modal-gallery').on('beforeLoad', function() {
    $(document)
      .off('mousewheel.modal-gallery')
      .off('DOMMouseScroll.modal-gallery')
      .off('keydown.modal-gallery');
    });
});
```

Comment: Giving a bit more context to the answer and a link to where you found this would improve your answer.